# Aspen Plus: Execute command line through Fortran Calculator

Tags: python, command-line, fortran, intel-fortran, aspen

I am working on a simulation which needs a calculator to call some Python models I made. My strategy is to use Fortran i/o functions to write export values, call Python programs through command prompt and read their outputs as import values from Fortran. I don't have too much experience working with Fortran, here is my code (wrote inside Aspen Plus Calculator):

```
  open(unit=1, file="in.txt")
  open(unit=2, file="bioprox.txt")
  open(unit=3, file="bioult.txt")
  open(unit=4, file="biosul.txt")

  write(1,*) WATER, ACID, BIOMASS
  write(2,'(1x,f4.2)') BIOPROX
  write(3,'(1x,f6.3)') BIOULT
  write(4,'(1x,f4.2)') BIOSUL


  close(1)
  close(2)
  close(3)
  close(4)
```

This works fine, but when I try to call terminal I get some errors. If I add the following statement:

```
  call execute_command_line("mkdir hey")
```

> ****TERMINAL ERROR
>           COULD NOT LOAD DYNAMIC LOAD MODULE
>
> ---
>
> - ERROR SEVERITY LEVEL OF  0 IS <= ABORT LEVEL OF  0              *
> - EXECUTION IS TERMINATED: SIMULATION WILL NOT BE EXECUTED        *
>
>   ---
>
>   ! Errors while processing input specifications

An if I use system calling:

```
  call system("mkdir hey")
```

> *** SEVERE ERROR
>         ERROR DURING DYNAMIC LINK OF USER ROUTINE(S) OR IN-LINE FORTRAN
>         PLEASE CHECK FILE _3340afg.ld FOR LINKER MESSAGES.
>
> *** SEVERE ERROR
>         COULD NOT RESOLVE USER OR IN-LINE FORTRAN SUBROUTINE(S):
>
> *** SUBROUTINE "ZZFORT" IS MISSING
>
> *** SEVERE ERROR
>         PROGRAM TERMINATED DUE TO UNRESOLVED ROUTINES
>
> ! Errors while processing input specifications

Checking the linker file:

> _3340afg.txt : error LNK2019: símbolo externo _SYSTEM@8 sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función _ZZFORT
>   _3340afg.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 externos sin resolver Link failure, status = 1120

I am using Aspen Plus V10, Intel Fortran Compiler 18 and Visual Studio 2017. But Aspen is which compiles and does linking functions. Any clue of what is wrong? Is it possible to do what I am trying?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: `My strategy is to use Fortran i/o functions to write export values`. Why don't you call the Fortran routines directly from Python?